# Deserialize from Postgres into DateTime by default (instead of TimeWithZone)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, time

I'm running Ruby on Rails 4.2.0 with Postgres 9.4.

I have a column associated with one of my models declared as `t.datetime` in my `schema.rb`. I can set the model's corresponding attribute to a DateTime and save that into the database.

However, when I retrieve the model from the database, my saved `DateTime` is deserialized into a `TimeWithZone` (a Rails class that wraps an instance of `Time`). How do I make Rails deserialize my Postgres `DATETIME` into an instance of Ruby's `DateTime` instead?

Currently I have an after_initialize callback defined in my model which converts any set Time/TimeWithZone instances to DateTimes, but I find this is an unsatisfactory solution.